# convergence in measure implies integral goes to zero

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Prove if $f_n$ converges to $0$ in measure and $\mu$ is a finite measure, then

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_X \frac{f_n}{1+\vert f_n \vert} d \mu = 0$$

So I know that if $f_n$ converges to $0$ in measure, then
$$\mu(\{x \in X: \vert f_n(x) \vert > \epsilon\})=0$$

Any hints would be greatly appreciated. I wanna say I can maybe bound the integral using triangle inequality? But unsure if that would work.

Comment: Apply dominated convergence theorem

Comment: so do I define $g_n:= \frac{f_n}{1+\vert f_n \vert}$ and the $f_n$ are dominated by the $g_n$?

Comment: $g_n \to 0$ in measure and $g_n$ is dominated by $1$ which is integrable (since the measure is finite).

Comment: sorry, meant for $n \geq N$, the measure is zero.

Comment: Convergence in measure means that the limit of that set is zero for any $\epsilon > 0$.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_in_measure)

Comment: If by bounding  the integral you mean $|\int ...| \leqslant \int |...|$, then yes that is a step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $E_n = \{x \in X: |f_n(x)| > \epsilon\}$ and note that

$$x \in E_n \implies\frac{|f_n|}{1+|f_n|} > \frac{\epsilon}{1 + \epsilon}, \quad x \in X \setminus E_n  \implies\frac{|f_n|}{1+|f_n|} \leqslant \frac{\epsilon}{1 + \epsilon}$$

Comment: I am a bit more confused now, so do I need to split up the integral into $\int_{E_n}+\int_{X \setminus E_n}$?

Comment: Yes $\int_X \frac{|f_n|}{1+|f_n|} = \int_{E_n} + \int_{X\setminus E_n}$